# shouldInterceptRequest() method is not calling for all the resources

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I have implemented webviewclient in my code for accessing some html content in my android code. I have given condition in shouldInterceptRequest() method to get the call of mp3 file so that i can change it on runtime. on the first day it was implemented successfully but now the method is  never calling that mp3 files i haven't changed the code yet but still I am not getting where i am doing wrong

My Html file is stored in local for now i have stored it manually but it will be downloaded from php server. My Implemented WebView Client is below

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            MSLogger.msLogD("initSleave", "WebViewClient: " + url + "\nview: " + view);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String request) {
            if (request.contains(".mp3")) {
                if (prefs.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("Hi")) {
                    try {
                   request= request.replace(".mp3", "_hindi.mp3");
                    request=request.replace("file://","");
                        return new WebResourceResponse("audio/mp3", "UTF-8", new FileInputStream(request));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Log.d("RequestView", "----->" + request);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Log.d("RequestView", "----->" + request);
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
    });
```

I want when the webclient will call mp3 resource file mentioned in my Sleave(Html) content. But its only calling all png, ttf,css and xmls now

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type parameter for .mp3 should be changed to audio/mpeg

doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

=O